# Unable to Update Firebase user table with userId

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-edittext

In here I create a 'Firebase' user in the signup process with 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password'. After successful login I load all signup values to another screen with new two "Edittext'. Now I need to update that signup table by 'Firebase' 'userId' with new two values 'country' and 'occupation' that is entered in new 'EditText'. For do that signup process and add new values  I used "UserProfileBean' class.

below is the code.

```
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("new_user");
        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid=user.getUid();


        final UserProfileBean userProfileBean = new UserProfileBean();
        userProfileBean.setCountry(country.getText().toString());
        userProfileBean.setOccupation(occupation.getText().toString());

        Log.d("UPDATE_PROFILE", "UPDATE_PROFILE_DATA" + userid + "," +
                userProfileBean.getOccupation() + ", " + userProfileBean.getCountry());

        //myRef.child(userid).child("country").setValue(userProfileBean.getCountry());

        Query pendingTasks = myRef.child(userid).orderByChild("country").equalTo("");
        pendingTasks.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: tasksSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    snapshot.getRef().child("country").setValue(userProfileBean.getCountry());
                    snapshot.getRef().child("occupation").setValue(userProfileBean.getOccupation());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

above code is implemented by button 'onclickListener'.

Comment: new_user database is having user table that is not entering country and occupation values at the signup process. after signup process I need to enter that both values to the user table.

Comment: What is the problem? I.e. when you run the code through a debugger, does it go into `onDataChange`? Does it go into the loop? If you then look at `snapshot.getKey()` does it have the value you expect? Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to tell us what's happening when you run the code.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: code is go inside the onDataChange. not to the for loop, public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
                Log.d("UPDATE_PROFILE", "INSIDE_DATACHANGED");
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: tasksSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Log.d("UPDATE_PROFILE", "INSIDE_LOOP");
                    snapshot.getRef().child("country").setValue(userProfileBean.getCountry());
                    snapshot.getRef().child("occupation").setValue(userProfileBean.getOccupation());
                }
            }

Comment: A number of your questions are requesting special or priority attention. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

To update the user node, try the following:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(useruid);

 Map<String,Object> update=new HashMap<>();
 update.put("Country",userProfileBean.getCountry());
 update.put("Occupation",userProfileBean.getOccupation());

ref.updateChildren(update);
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: I made the changes. but nothing.

Comment: change the child("User") to child("new_user") the node that you have in your database