# Unable to update Firebase Node

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap, android-edittext

How can I update the Firebase node by using 'refKey'. Here I have five strings came from 'EditText'. I need to update the node called 'appreciate' by using its 'refkey'. I got 'refKey' as a 'string' parameter called 'key'. Below is the code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void updateAppreciatedSomeone(final EditText subject, final EditText first, final EditText second, final EditText third,
                                      final EditText date1, final String key){

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    Query query = reference.child("appreciate").equalTo(key);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot nodeDataSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
            String key1 = nodeDataSnapshot.getKey(); //
            String path = "/" + dataSnapshot.getKey() + "/" + key1;
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();               

            // to update appreciate nodeDataSnapshot

            result.put("appreciatedWhom", first.getText().toString());
            result.put("appreciatedWhy",second.getText().toString());
            result.put("appreciatedDateTime", date.getText().toString();
            result.put("appreciatedDescription",third.getText().toString());
            result.put("appreciatedSubject", subject.getText().toString());
            reference.child(path).updateChildren(result);

            Log.d("UPDATE_APPRECIATION", "APPRECIATION_UPDATED_FOR:" + result);

            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("UPDATE_PROFILE", ">>> Error:" + "find onCancelled:" + databaseError);

        }
    });
}
```

While I run this code following exception is occurred.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:59)
        at com.google.firebase.database.zzb.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.threeiteam.karma.MainActivity$41.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:1357)
        at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But this code is working for update the 'user node' by using following code.

```
Query query = reference.child("user").orderByChild("email").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
```

Comment: Please add  your database structure.

Comment: I've [asked you to refrain from urgent begging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50061554) on one of your earlier posts. Your questions will not be treated as a greater priority than other people's questions.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you create inside an event listener will not be available for use outside of that event listener. What I did for solving this issue was to declare the hashmap as a member variable of the class, fill it inside an event listener and use it where ever it is needed.

Comment: I have used only that hash map inside the listner.